# Tshark read offline file start so slow

Tags: solaris, tshark

I execute tshark (wireshark utility) command that reading from pcap file. Process is too slow. Sometimes take more than 6-7 seconds. Pcap file is really small (~500bytes). Actually strange thing is that re-execute same command consequently, process duration is decreasing dramatically. After wait about half minute (without execution command), re-run same command and process completion duration increase again. Why process behave like that? How to check what is going on in deep?

Command :

`tshark -r test.pcap`

OS : 
SunOS er 5.10 Generic_147441-01 i86pc i386 i86pc

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to DNS resolution of hostnames. Add the [`-n`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/tshark.1.html) parameter to disable this and see if it speeds it up:

```
tshark -n -r test.pcap
```

If this solves the issue you probably want to enable MAC and port number lookups again like this:

```
tshark -N mt -r test.pcap
```

You could also try the asynchronous DNS lookup by adding `C` to that list:

```
tshark -N mtC -r test.pcap
```

Comment: -n parameter is not changed anything